# Need help while connecting Websocket server from Client

Tags: socket.io, nodes, ngrok, vonage

I have a sample application (Node Js,Socket.io,ngrok)for getting live data streaming from NexmoLive Call.We are able to get the data using voicebase transcription from WebSocket node in console, when i try to open the client socket , the server socket get closed and ngrok gets `502 BadGateway` Exception, I have added the server and socket code below

**Socket.js**

```
   var socket = io("https://0302de8a.ngrok.io");
var actionItems = []
var beginTakingAction = false

var strOut;
socket.on('transcript', function(x) {
  var div = $('div.transcription')
  div.html(x);
  console.log("transcript " + x);
  if (!scrolling) {
      div.scrollTop(div[0].scrollHeight);
    }
})

socket.on('action', function(x) {
  console.log('sending action',x);
  actionItems.push(x)
  $('div.action').html(actionItems[actionItems.length-1]);

})
socket.on('sentiment', function(x) {
  sentimentChart.update(x)
})

socket.on('nlp', function(x) {
  wordLengthDistChart.update(x.wordLenghDist);
  posTagDistChart.update(x.posTagDist);
})

socket.on('keywords', function(x) {
    keywordChart.update(x)
})

socket.on('status', function(status) {
    $('div.status').html("status: " + status);

    if (status == "connected") {
      sentimentChart.reset()
      keywordChart.reset()
      wordLengthDistChart.reset()
      posTagDistChart.reset()
      $('div.transcription').html('');
    }

})
```

**server**

```
require('dotenv').config()
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Nexmo = require('nexmo');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var util = require("util");
const winston = require('winston')

var executed = false;
var didStart = false
var USER_NUMBER = ""
var WEB_SOCKET = 'ws://' + process.env.WEB_SOCKET_URL + '/socket';

var SMS_TEXT = "View the transcription service here: " + "http://" + process.env.WEB_SOCKET_URL;
var converstationIDs = [];
var connectedUsers = [];

var nexmo = new Nexmo({
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    apiSecret: process.env.API_SECRET,
    applicationId: process.env.APPLICATION_ID,
    privateKey: __dirname + '/' + process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PATH
},
    { debug: process.env.NEXMO_DEBUG }
);

winston.level = process.env.LOG_LEVEL
var calls = Promise.promisifyAll(nexmo.calls);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080)
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

winston.log('debug', 'env vars', process.env);

app.get('/answer', function (req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    winston.log('info', 'answer route called', req.body);
    reset()
    var url = require('url');
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;

    connectedUsers.push(query.from);
    winston.log('debug', 'adding user to sms list', connectedUsers);
    if (process.env.SINGLE_USER) {
        winston.log('debug', 'In single user mode');
        var json = [
            {
                "action": "connect",
                "eventUrl": [
                    "https://call-dev.url.net/events"
                ],
                "from": process.env.NEXMO_NUMBER,
                "endpoint": [
                    {
                        "type": "websocket",
                        "uri": WEB_SOCKET,
                        "content-type": "audio/l16;rate=16000",
                        "headers": {
                            "app": "audiosocket"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
        winston.log('info', 'conference JSON', json);
        res.send(json)
        return
    }

    if (process.env.TO_NUMBER) {
        var json = [
            {
                "action": "talk",
                "text": "Calling user"
            },
            {
                "action": "conversation",
                "name": process.env.CONFERENCE_NAME,
                "endOnExit": "true"
            }
        ]

        var to = {
            type: 'phone',
            number: process.env.TO_NUMBER,
        }
        winston.log('info', 'answer JSON', json);
        dial(to, process.env.NEXMO_NUMBER, req.headers.host, function (result) {
            winston.log('info', 'dial result', result);
            res.send(json)
        })

    } else {
        var baseURL = "http://" + req.headers.host;
        var json = [
            {
                "action": "talk",
                "text": "Please enter a phone number to call, press the pound key when complete",
                "bargeIn": "false"
            },
            {
                "action": "input",
                "submitOnHash": true,
                "timeOut": 60,
                "maxDigits": 20,
                "eventUrl": [baseURL + "/events_ivr"]
            },
            {
                "action": "conversation",
                "name": process.env.CONFERENCE_NAME,
                "endOnExit": "true",
            }
        ]

        winston.log('info', 'answer JSON', json);
        res.send(json)
    }
})

app.get('/conference', function (req, res) {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    var url = require('url');
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = url_parts.query;
    var json = [
        {
            "action": "talk",
            "text": "Dialing into the conference now",
        },
        {
            "action": "conversation",
            "name": process.env.CONFERENCE_NAME,
            "startOnEnter": "false"
        }
    ]
    winston.log('info', 'conference JSON', json);
    res.send(json)
})

app.post('/events_ivr', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    winston.log('info', 'events_ivr', req.body);

    var baseURL = req.headers.host;
    var number = req.body.dtmf;
    var from = req.body.from;

    USER_NUMBER = number

    if (number == '' || number.length < 11) {
        winston.log('debug', 'could not get dtmf number', number);
        var json = [
            {
                "action": "talk",
                "text": "Sorry, I did not get that phone number. Goodbye"
            }
        ]
        res.send(json);
    } else {
        var to = {
            type: 'phone',
            number: number,
        }
        dial(to, process.env.NEXMO_NUMBER, baseURL, function (result) {
            winston.log('info', 'IVR Dial result', result);
        })

        res.sendStatus(200);
    }

});

app.post('/events', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    winston.log('info', 'events', req.body);

    var baseURL = req.headers.host;
    var from = req.body.from;

    if (req.body.status == "answered") {
        converstationIDs.push(req.body.uuid);
        winston.log('debug', 'adding converstaion uuid', converstationIDs);

        if (req.body.to != process.env.NEXMO_NUMBER && req.body.to != WEB_SOCKET) {
            connectedUsers.push(req.body.to);
            winston.log('debug', 'adding user to sms list', connectedUsers);
        }

        if (req.body.to == USER_NUMBER || req.body.to == process.env.TO_NUMBER) {

            var to = {
                type: 'websocket',
                uri: WEB_SOCKET,
                "content-type": "audio/l16;rate=16000",
                "headers": {
                    "app": "audiosocket"
                }
            }
            winston.log('debug', 'calling websocket', req.body);
            dial(to, from, baseURL, function (result) {
                winston.log('debug', 'called websocket', result);
                sendAllSms(SMS_TEXT, function () {
                    winston.log('info', 'all sms sent');
                })
            })
            res.sendStatus(200);
            return

        }
    }
    else if (req.body.status == "completed") {
        winston.log('debug', 'called ended', req.body);
        winston.log('debug', 'calling hangup');
        performHangup()
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

var performHangup = (function () {
    return function () {
        winston.log('debug', "executed " + executed + " didStart " + didStart)
        if (!executed && !didStart) {
            didStart = true
            hangupCalls(function () {
                executed = true;
                winston.log('info', 'hangup complete');
            })
        }
    };
})();

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason) => {
    winston.log('error', 'unhandledRejection', reason)
});

;

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    winston.log('info', 'Nexmo Phone app listening on port ' + (process.env.PORT || 8080))
})


function dial(to, from, serverURL, callback) {
    var json = {
        to: [to],
        from: {
            type: 'phone',
            number: from
        },
        answer_url: ['http://' + serverURL + '/conference'],
        event_url: ['http://' + serverURL + '/events', 'http://' + process.env.WEB_SOCKET_URL + '/events']
    }
    winston.debug('debug', 'dial JSON', json);
    calls.createAsync(json).then(function (res) {
        winston.log('debug', 'call created', res)
        callback(res)
    })
}

function hangupCalls(callback) {
    Promise.each(converstationIDs, function (converstationID) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            calls.updateAsync(converstationID, { action: 'hangup' })
                .then(function (resp) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        winston.log('info', 'hangup result: for id: ' + converstationID, resp)
                        resolve();
                    }, 2000)

                })
        });

    })
        .then(function (allItems) {
            winston.log('debug', 'all items', allItems)
            callback();
        })
}

function terminate(callback) {
    winston.log('debug', 'calling terminate');
    var request = require('request');
    request({
        url: 'http://' + process.env.WEB_SOCKET_URL + '/terminate',
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        winston.log('debug', 'terminate called');
        callback()
    })
}

function sendAllSms(message, callback) {

    Promise.each(connectedUsers, function (phoneNumber) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            sendSMS(phoneNumber, SMS_TEXT, function (resp) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    winston.log('info', 'sending sms to phoneNumber: ' + phoneNumber, resp)
                    resolve();
                }, 1000)
            })
        });
    })
        .then(function (allItems) {
            winston.log('debug', 'all items', allItems)
            callback();
        })
}

function sendSMS(phoneNumber, message, callback) {
    var https = require('https');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
        api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
        to: phoneNumber,
        from: process.env.NEXMO_NUMBER,
        text: message
    });

    var options = {
        host: 'rest.nexmo.com',
        path: '/sms/json',
        port: 443,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }
    };

    var req = https.request(options);

    req.write(data);
    req.end();

    var responseData = '';
    req.on('response', function (res) {
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            responseData += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            callback(JSON.parse(responseData))
        });
    });
}

function reset() {
    connectedUsers.length = 0
    converstationIDs.length = 0;
    executed = false;
    didStart = false
}

socket.on('action', function(x) {
  console.log('sending action',x);
  actionItems.push(x)
  $('div.action').html(actionItems[actionItems.length-1]);

})
socket.on('sentiment', function(x) {
  sentimentChart.update(x)
})

socket.on('nlp', function(x) {
  wordLengthDistChart.update(x.wordLenghDist);
  posTagDistChart.update(x.posTagDist);
})

socket.on('keywords', function(x) {
    keywordChart.update(x)
})

socket.on('status', function(status) {
    $('div.status').html("status: " + status);

    if (status == "connected") {
      sentimentChart.reset()
      keywordChart.reset()
      wordLengthDistChart.reset()
      posTagDistChart.reset()
      $('div.transcription').html('');
    }

})
```

**console**

```
+ socket.io@2.0.4
updated 1 package in 2.522s
PS D:\workspace projects\new\Nexmo-RTS-Voicebase\WS-node> npm start

> ws-node@1.0.0 start D:\workspace projects\new\Nexmo-RTS-Voicebase\WS-node
> node app.js

info: Server listening on :8000
info: handleRequest /
info: loading index
info: port
info: handleRequest /public/voicebase.png
info: handleRequest /public/nexmo.png
info: handleRequest /public/js/charts.js
info: handleRequest /public/js/socket.js
info: A client is connected!
info: handleRequest /favicon.ico
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: This socket is closed
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:726:18)
    at Socket._write (net.js:786:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:387:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:373:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:704:40)
    at WebSocketRequest.accept (D:\workspace projects\new\Nexmo-RTS-Voicebase\WS-node\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketRequest.js:450:21)
    at WebSocketServer.handleUpgrade (D:\workspace projects\new\Nexmo-RTS-Voicebase\WS-node\node_modules\websocket\lib\WebSocketServer.js:216:19)
    at emitThree (events.js:141:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:217:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ws-node@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws-node@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**Error in NGROK**

[ngrok console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0K6T.png)

Answer (score 0):

This only happened when your server is not running;.